# Does implementing graalvm on a spring batch application improve its performance

Tags: spring-batch, graalvm

Am working on a spring batch job that processes millions of records during a period of 5-6 hrs every time it's run.

The application runs of java 8 and i was wondering if making that batch job run on graalvm would add any significant performance.

Comment: I would be interested in your experience with that. Have you compiled your Spring batch job into a native image with GraalVM and compared the results with a regular JVM?

Answer (score 0):

It could (should even), but best measure for yourself.

Switching to GraalVM should be a matter of changing JAVA_HOME or whatever path to java you use, run your job and see how long it takes.

If you have the time/resources run the same job both with your usual JVM and with GraalVM and see if using GraalVM helps on your workload.

Comment: Thanks Boris. To be honest, i tried that in a dev environment with two records being processed by the job, whereas the production one runs for a load of around 5-10 million records. I noticed in dev environment it took more time to run that job on graalvm than on a regular jvm. It got me confused and led to asking this question eventually. I still want to run it on heavier workload though

Comment: Yeah, heavier workload would be much more representative.

Comment: Cool. Thanks boris